# plainto_tsquery in english config is stemming the given words into incorrect root words. Ex : "create" -> "creat", "scheduled" -> "schedul"

Tags: java, sql, postgresql, pgadmin-4, tsvector

I am trying to convert the given query word into a ts_query which I can use in the where condition for select query. I am not getting the records in query as this plainto_tsquery is giving the invalid root word for English config.

**Database demo table :**

| id | ts_vector |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | create:1,test:2 |
| 3 | schedule:1,test:2 |

**Query :** select * from demo where ts_vector @@ plainto_tsquery("english","create")

0 records

**Query :** select * from demo where ts_vector @@ plainto_tsquery("simple","create")

| id | ts_vector |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | create:1,test:2 |

found that the issue is in the plainto_tsquery with English config, it stems the given words as below. so the query is returning 0 records as there are no records with the given root words in ts_vector.

`select plainto_tsquery("English","create")`

'creat'

`select plainto_tsquery("simple","schedule")`

'schedul'

Why is this happening? is 'creat' the root word for create in English? I have updated the Postgres dictionary but no change in the result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is working as expected.

The English text search configuration uses the [Snowball dictionary](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/textsearch-dictionaries.html#TEXTSEARCH-SNOWBALL-DICTIONARY) `english_stem` for natural language words:

```
\dF+ english

Text search configuration "pg_catalog.english"
Parser: "pg_catalog.default"
      Token      │ Dictionaries 
═════════════════╪══════════════
 asciihword      │ english_stem
 asciiword       │ english_stem
 email           │ simple
 file            │ simple
 float           │ simple
 host            │ simple
 hword           │ english_stem
 hword_asciipart │ english_stem
 hword_numpart   │ simple
 hword_part      │ english_stem
 int             │ simple
 numhword        │ simple
 numword         │ simple
 sfloat          │ simple
 uint            │ simple
 url             │ simple
 url_path        │ simple
 version         │ simple
 word            │ english_stem
```

The Snowball dictionary does not understand the language, so that it can stem correctly, but it uses heuristics for stemming that are usually good enough. However, "creat" is the correct stemming for "create": think of "creating".

If you created the `tsvector` using the `simple` text search configuration, you cannot expect to find it with a `tsquery` that was generated with a different text search configuration.